# Trying to access a list from another web application, but getting an error 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: list, 401, cross-domain, pnp-js-core

I'm a Sharepoint beginner, I'm trying to access a list which is in another site collection under another web application in the same farm. I'm working with pnp core js library.

`new pnp.Web("http://mycollectionsiteurl/").lists.getByTitle('Emloyee').items.get().then((result: any)`
But I'm getting this error :

`OPTIONS http:///_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Employee')/items 401 (Unauthorized) Fetch API cannot load http://mycollectionsiteurl/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Employee')/items. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401`

Please tell me how can i resolve this problem ? 
thanks.

Comment: Same error here: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/issues/230

Answer (score 0):

As you are requesting list from the another web application or site collection that's why it is giving unauthorized error code 401 in response.

Make sure you have rights there in that web application or site collection too.

Comment: and how or where can I make sure if I have these rights ?

Comment: @wissem As you have told that you are trying to access the list which is not in a current web application or site collection.so make sure that you have rights in "mycollectionsiteurl" from your URL where your list resides.